# Location is experimental in dataset creation

Tags: google-bigquery

Location parameter is experimental in [dataset creation method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets).

I would like to know what are the implications of this experimental feature and also if the difference between US and EU is appreciable when uploading or querying data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just was waiting for more answers. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimental is a way to tell in the documentation that code might change in the future, and it's not covered by the standard SLA. This would mean the API call can be deprecated or changed without a proper pre-announcement. However this should not stop you to use it.

Otherwise the only limitation I am aware of, is that you cannot join across tables that are in different `location`. You cannot combine for example a public database which is in US to a EU table of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!